# MS Access SQL - How to search multiple fields with one LIKE operator

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access VBA

```
Dim search As String

"SELECT Identifier
FROM tblProjects
WHERE Identifier 
LIKE '*" & search & "*' " & _
"OR Title LIKE '*" & search & "*' " & _
"OR Regions LIKE '*" & search & "*' " & _
"OR ProjectDate LIKE '*" & search & "*' " & _
(etc)
```

Is there a way to shorten this query so that it uses one LIKE operator? Pretty much I want to search each column if they contain the search value. Keep in mind this is using the MS Access database.

Comment: You could select all the text-fields into a concatenated field in a temporary result, and then do a `LIKE` on the temporary result-set.

Comment: concatenate the values (identifier & title & regions &projectDate...) like '*search*' but this could be slower;

Comment: `[ABC]+[XYZ]`  would match `*CX*` which does not exist as a discreet value, you would need to stuff in delimiters to fix that which is pretty horrible compared to a nice optimisable OR series.

Comment: You could add a lookup field, and look at using data macros to do add the concatenated values to this field, on update/delete etc as this might make querying a little quicker as you could add an index to the field.  I favour the separate OR method tbh.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work, but I personally don't see why you can't have the existing disjunctive logic... it makes a lot more sense.

```
SELECT Identifier
FROM tblProjects
WHERE (Identifier + '|' + Title + '|' + Regions + '|' + ...) 
    LIKE '*search_text*'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, may work, but I'm in favour of the OR's, but is horizontal.

```
select q1.id,t2.id from
(select t1.id,t1.value1 from table1 as t1 where t1.[Title]='a') as q1
left join table1 as t2 on t2.[Regions]=q1.[Title]
```